# symplectic base in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Please, can somebody help me? In the vectorial space $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$,is the canonical basis a symplectic one?

Comment: With respect to what symplectic bilinear form ?

Comment: Are you referring to the dot product?

Comment: Yes, @Bebop....

Comment: No, to the symplectic product....

Comment: With respect to the $[x,y]=<x,Jy$, where $J$ is a matrix with $2n$ lines and $2n$ coloumns,  $J$ is formed on the blocks $O_{n}, I_{n}, -I_{n}, O_{n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we can *construct* a symplectic basis from the canonical one, and prove that it is symplectic using block-matrix multiplication.  In particular: let $e_1,\dots,e_{2n}$ denote the canonical basis.  Let $\bar e_1,\dots,\bar e_n$ denote the canonical basis of $\Bbb R^n$. Define
$$
x_i = e_i, \quad y_i = e_{n + i}
$$
We then have:
$$
x_i^TJx_j = \pmatrix{\bar e_i^T & 0} \pmatrix{0&I\\-I&0}\pmatrix{\bar e_j\\0} = \bar e_i^T0\bar e_j = 0\\
y_i^TJy_j = \pmatrix{0&\bar e_i^T} \pmatrix{0&I\\-I&0}\pmatrix{0\\\bar e_j} = \bar e_i^T0\bar e_j = 0\\
x_i^TJy_j = \pmatrix{\bar e_i^T&0} \pmatrix{0&I\\-I&0}\pmatrix{0\\\bar e_j} = \bar e_i^TI\bar e_j = \delta_{ij}
$$
thus, the $x_i$ and $y_i$ form a symplectic basis.